# HTML/CSS Cross Browser Inconsistency with SVG

Tags: html, css, svg, browser

I have have been tinkering, trying to get images to render consistently across browser.

**HTML:**

```
<fieldset class="legend">
    <img class="legend-a"/>
    <img class="legend-b"/>
    <img class="legend-c"/>
    <img class="legend-d"/>
    <img class="legend-e"/>
</fieldset>
```

**CSS:**

```
.legend {border: 0; display: inline;}
.legend-a{ background: url(yellow.svg); }
.legend-b{ background: url(orange.svg);}
.legend-c { background: url(purple.svg);}
.legend-d { background: url(dull_purple.svg); }
.legend-e { background: url(blue.svg);}
```

Currently the above works fine (the images display in a row side by side) for IE (Version 11) But not (blank, no images) in Chrome or Firefox.

Previously I had used `content: url(purple.svg);` instead of `background: url(purple.svg);` but that only worked in Chrome; but not in IE or FireFox.

It's very bothersome. I have to keep the `<fieldset.../>` HTML as succinct as possible as it is repeated all over the place, as `<td>`

The .svg look like this (for example)
**blue.svg:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     viewBox="0 0 36.232 36.232" enable-background="new 0 0 36.232 36.232" xml:space="preserve">
<circle fill="#37ADC4" cx="17.981" cy="18.179" r="16"/>
</svg>
```

Here's a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/declantreanor/jj6t88es/) . Only the 'content' version works with JFiddle.

Comment: can you make an [Fiddle?](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: I wouldn't be able to upload any files (svgs) to anywhere from work. Tight security.

Comment: replace it with his one https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/02/SVG_logo.svg

Comment: Add a explicit width and height values to the root `<svg>` element. And can you explain what not working means?

Comment: Not working means that the images do not display. Blank, no images. Not displaying in JSFiddle either (unless I use 'content: url(...')

Comment: The image works for me. Also, remove the xml version thing (forgot what it's called). Then try it but I don't know why you think the "yellow.svg" would work cause there is no such thing in the markup you show.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats because your `<img>`s don't have a size. If you provide a size then the background renders as well. I don't know what size IE would pick in this case anyways...?

```css
.legend {border: 0; display: inline;}
.legend-a{ background: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/02/SVG_logo.svg); }
.legend-b{ background: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/02/SVG_logo.svg);}
.legend-c { background: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/02/SVG_logo.svg);}
.legend-d { background: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/02/SVG_logo.svg); }
.legend-e { background: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/02/SVG_logo.svg);}

.legend img{width:32px;height:32px}
```

```html
<fieldset class="legend">
    <img class="legend-a"/>
    <img class="legend-b"/>
    <img class="legend-c"/>
    <img class="legend-d"/>
    <img class="legend-e"/>
</fieldset>
```